# Sorting a text file in Java

Tags: java, file, sorting, text

I have a text file  with a list of words which I need to sort in alphabetical order using Java. The words are located on seperate lines.

How would I go about this, Read them into an array list and then sort that??

Comment: Sort of an off-topic answer, but how about
`$ sort filename > sorted.txt`

Comment: Your idea may work if the file data fits in memory.

Comment: The file is a dictionary of words. 1.1 mbs. Over 1000 words??

Comment: 1.1MB is nothing. If you can't use sort from the command line, read it into an array of strings and then sort them.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [Sort ArrayList alphabetically][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496841/sort-arraylist-alphabetically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple four step process, with three of the four steps addressed by Stackoverflow Questions:

1. [Read each line and turn them into Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868369/how-to-read-a-large-text-file-line-by-line-in-java)
2. Store each Java String in a Array (don't think you need a reference for this one.)
3. [Sort your Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496841/sort-arraylist-alphabetically)
4. [Write out each Java String in your array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/simplest-way-to-print-an-array-in-java)

Comment: +1 for referencing posts that already exist, and not being a jerk about it

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class example
{
    TreeSet<String> tree=new TreeSet<String>();
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new example().go();
    }
    public void go()

    {
        getlist();
        System.out.println(tree);

    }
     void getlist()
    {
        try
        {
            File myfile= new File("C:/Users/Rajat/Desktop/me.txt");
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(myfile));
            String line=null;
            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                addnames(line);


            }
        reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    void addnames(String a)
    {
           tree.add(a);
           for(int i=1;i<=a.length();i++)
           {

           }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Collections sort:

```
public static void sortFile() throws IOException
{     
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("C:\\words.txt");
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        lines.add(line);
    }
    bufferedReader.close();

    Collections.sort(lines, Collator.getInstance());

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\wordsnew.txt"); 
    for(String str: lines) {
      writer.write(str + "\r\n");
    }
    writer.close();
}
```

You can also use your own collation like this:

```
Locale lithuanian = new Locale("lt_LT");
Collator lithuanianCollator = Collator.getInstance(lithuanian);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public List<String> readFile(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<String> txtLines = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
        String line;
        while (!((line = reader.readLine()) == null)) {
            txtLines.add(line);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return txtLines.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```